# Search on two fields with spell mistakes or synonyms

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have below requirement,

there are two attributes which are searchable

1.name 2 mode-name

records in index

[{'name': 'testing', 'mode-name': 'myunit'}, {'name': 'flipkart', 'mode-name': 'ecommerce'}]

user is given the search like,

**find tst in myunt**

to this search query, i want to get the *first* record.

Any suggestion please

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the goal is. Can you provide any more information, such as the language or framework you're using?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use synonyms, you need to provide a list of known synonyms for your corpus:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-synonyms

If you want "light" spell correction, you can use fuzzy search:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-fuzzy

In your example, fuzzy search should work to return the first record with the given query.